# Event undefined issue in onbeforeunload function

Tags: javascript

I am using following code. But I am getting result as event is undefined. What could be the possible reasons for this?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
      if(window.event.clientX < 0 && window.event.clientY <0){
          alert('Browser close button clicked'); 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.event` is not a standard in all browsers. Use the `event` argument of the handler function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
      if(event.clientX < 0 && event.clientY <0){
          alert('Browser close button clicked'); 
      }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Do what? Question is very vague

Comment: how to Use the event argument of the handler function?